# Why is my font not Trebuchet MS

Tags: html, css

I want to use Trebuchet MS for the sidebar - On Dreamweaver the font shows up exactly how I want it, but when I look at in the live view, the font changes to an ugly font.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a Href=""><i class="fa fa-list"> Home</i></a></li>
<li><a Href=""><i class="fa fa-list"> Profile</i></a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
position: fixed;
width: 170px;
margin-left: -170px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8); 
}
#nav ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#nav li a:link, #nav li a:visited{
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 90%;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
border-left: 5px solid #26a9ec;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
}
#nav li a:hover{
background-color: #26a9ec;
color: #fff;
}
#nav .active a, #nav .active a:visited{
background-color: #1a1aff;
color: #fff;
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your browser simply doesn't support it? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, Safari, and Firefox > Tested on all and the font changes to Times New Roman.

Comment: Is this all of your CSS? Maybe you have another style overriding it somewhere. This code works (see my answer).

Comment: Make sure your System ( PC ) installed the fonts

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your browser simply doesn't support it.

For example, [when I ran your code on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/618y9pg0/), the Trebuchet MS font showed up just fine.

There shouldn't be anything wrong with `font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;` - it worked just fine for me.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using an icon font (Font Awesome) and you wrapped the copy in `<i>` tags.

`<i class="fa fa-list"> Home</i>`

Should be:

`<i class="fa fa-list"></i> Home`

I realise this is a question from 2015, but just in case someone ends up here.